# Adding wordpress comments to custom table in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a plugin in wordpress which will have two custom tables,Category and City tables.

I want to use wordpress comments functionality for commenting on each particular city.
Custom post would have solved the problem but cities table have large data as well as many attributes.

There any way user can add wordpress comments on cities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you aren't basing your new City object off of a WordPress Custom Post Type, you will have to write your own code to handle it.  I would suggest having a city_comments table to store those comments separately. (Re-using the WP comments table would be ugly and cause you a bunch of grief).

Comment: Thanks Adam. My city object has nearly 10 attributes and 10k cities. So is it safe to create Wordpress custom post type for city.

Comment: It is safe, but might not be the most efficient.